# Tags: If "A" in My Tags, and "B" in Ignore, and a post has "A" and "B", I'd like to see it

Tags: support, tag-watching, ignored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Provide “Keep Interesting Tags” option when “Hide Ignored Tags” enabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/provide-keep-interesting-tags-option-when-hide-ignored-tags-enabled)

But I don't.

Is there a setting I can toggle to get that behavior?

If not, I'd like to request a feature.......

Comment: How can this question of 2009 be marked as duplicate of a question in 2010? And why are there 2 moderators needed to mark it as duplicate? Sometimes I don't understand SE.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution proposal

In my opinion the real solution would be to merge the two separate `interesting` and `ignore` lists
into one single list. Each element then has the property of either interesting or ignore and the order of the elements gives priority,
with the highest matching item "winning".

### Example 1

Linux user that normally wants to ignore windows/macintosh, but not for questions about writing portable code:

- unix: interesting
- linux: interesting
- portability: interesting
- windows: ignore
- machos: ignore

### Example 2

Windows user that normally ignores unix/linux, but has a special interest in security and would like to read
unix/linux questions related to that.

- windows: interesting
- security: interesting
- unix: ignore
- linux: ignore

### Example 3

User with no interest in any questions related to php whatsoever.

- php: ignore
- java: interesting
- something-else: interesting
- boring-stuff: ignore

This would give a much better control to the users of which questions to ignore or include.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the "hide questions on my ignore list" setting on your profile and they will show up as both interesting and ignored.

Comment: That's not really a solution though, if I truly want to hide questions on my ignore list.  I can't browse the main page of SO without it, as the questions come too fast too quickly and at least half are on topics I have no interest in.

Answer (score 0):

For those greasily inclined, I've updated [my interesting/ignored tags greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49704/double-intensity-shading-for-questions-with-1-interesting-tags/49724#49724) to support this feature. Now questions with "interesting" tags are always shown even if they're also tagged with an "ignored" tag, regardless of your "Hide Ignored Tags" setting (but keeps them faded out so you can still see they're "ignored").